# How can I align my form fields in Liferay Dynamic data Lists?

Tags: liferay, dynamic-data-list

I am using Dynamic Data List in Liferay 6.2 to create a form. I want the form fields to be ordered horizontally. But dragging the fields only lets me to align them vertically. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Form template can be modified through your data list data definitions:

*Site administration -> Dynamic data lists -> Manage data definitions -> YOUR Data Definition -> Actions -> Manage templates*

Here you can add new **form template**.

However, I was unable to order form fields horizontaly in the form template editor. There is also no mention about horizontal layout of form fields in the DDL [user documentation](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/using-web-forms-and-dynamic-data-lists-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-10-en) So I guess, it's not possible through portal configuration.

So maybe a hook could solve this.